# devise: user model not updating after permiting additional parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rubygems

I have created a model User with devise.
It contains extra fields firstname and lastname.
I have permitted these parameters in the application controller:

```
 def configure_permitted_parameters
        devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:firstname, :lastname, :email, :password])
        devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:firstname, :lastname, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password])
        
    end
```

But when I click on update, nothing is updated. In terminal it shows OK.

Comment: do you have a before_action for that method?? for example something like this in your ApplicationController `before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?`

Comment: Yes, I have added it. Even than it's not working.

Comment: This is the project I am working on. https://github.com/mmuneeburahman/kaarekamaal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no issue with the code, we need to enter the current password in order to update the information.